# Variable mysteriously changing value

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, tcp

EDIT: Ok I had a problem with one of the string concatenation functions, has nothing to do with threads, but knowing that it couldn't be a problem with threading lead me to the answer thank you for answering.

I am making a simple tcp/ip chat program for practicing threads and tcp/ip. I was using asynchronous methods but had a problem with concurrency so I went to threads and blocking methods (not asynchronous). I have two private variables defined in the class, not static:

```
string amessage = string.Empty;
int MessageLength;
```

and a Thread

```
private Thread BeginRead;
```

Ok so I call a function called Listen ONCE when the client starts:

```
public virtual void Listen(int byteLength)
        {
            var state = new StateObject {Buffer = new byte[byteLength]};
            BeginRead = new Thread(ReadThread);
            BeginRead.Start(state);                
        }
```

and finally the function to receive commands and process them, I'm going to shorten it because it is really long:

```
  private void ReadThread(object objectState)
    {
       var state = (StateObject)objectState;
       int byteLength = state.Buffer.Length;
       while (true)
          {

              var buffer = new byte[byteLength];
              int len = MySocket.Receive(buffer);
              if (len <= 0) return;               
              string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, len);
              amessage += cleanMessage.Substring(0, MessageLength);
              if (OnRead != null)
                {
                   var e = new CommandEventArgs(amessage);
                   OnRead(this, e);
                 }

           }

    }
```

Now, as I understand it only one thread at a time will enter `BeginRead`, I call `Receive`, it blocks until I get data, and then I process it. The problem: the variable `amessage` will change it's value between statements that do not touch or alter the variable at all, for example at the bottom of the function at: `if (OnRead != null)` "amessage" will be equal to 'asdf' and at `if (OnRead != null)` "amessage" will be equal to qwert.  As I understand it this is indicative of another thread changing the value/running asynchronously. I only spawn one thread to do the receiving and the Receive function is blocking, how could there be two threads in this function and if there is only one thread how does amessage's value change between statements that don't affect it's value. As a side note sorry for spamming the site with these questions but I'm just getting a hang of this threading story and it's making me want to sip cyanide.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is my code that calls the Listen Method in the client:

```
public void ConnectClient(string ip,int port)
        {

            client.Connect(ip,port);
            client.Listen(5);
        }
```

and in the server:

```
private void Accept(IAsyncResult result)
        {

                var client = new AbstractClient(MySocket.EndAccept(result));
                var e = new CommandEventArgs(client, null);
                    Clients.Add(client);
                    client.Listen(5);
                    if (OnClientAdded != null)
                    {
                        var target = (Control) OnClientAdded.Target;
                        if (target != null && target.InvokeRequired)
                            target.Invoke(OnClientAdded, this, e);
                        else
                            OnClientAdded(this, e);


                    }


                    client.OnRead += OnRead;
                    MySocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(Accept), null);

        }
```

All this code is in a class called AbstractClient. The client inherits the Abstract client and when the server accepts a socket it create's it's own local AbstractClient, in this case both modules access the functions above however they are different instances and I couldn't imagine threads from different instances combining especially as no variable is static.

Comment: You only call it *once* - can you show any of the code that calls `Listen`?

Comment: What is "cleanMessage"? What does OnRead do?

Comment: I used cleanMessage to take out the delimiters and the such, I took out the code because it's long and doesn't really have that much to do with the threading. OnRead is an event that has the entire message in MessageEventArgs. My buffer is only [5] for testing so usually the entire message is not sent in only one read.

Comment: Does `aMessage` really need to be a type member? From the code it appears a local would be good enough.

Comment: @Marc I edited the post to include the code that calls listen. I call it both from the server and the client.

Comment: Did you really clean out all async code, or may there be some leftovers in your code?

Comment: @leppie, my buffer is only like 5 so I can test it, usually the message isn't sent in only one receive call so I use aMessage to cocatenate the message and send it to OnRead when I'm finished.

Comment: @lucero The sending is asynchronous as well as the server accepting clients, in regards to receiving messages all the code I used is posted above although I did take out some things that have to do with string concatenation and the such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this makes no sense the way you described it.  Which probably means that what you *think* is going on is not what is really happening.  Debugging threaded code is quite difficult, very hard to capture the state of the program at the exact moment it misbehaves.

A generic approach is to add logging to your code.  Sprinkle your code with Debug.WriteLine() statements that shows the current value of the variable, along with the thread's ManagedId.  You get potentially a lot of output, but somewhere you'll see it going wrong.  Or you get enough insight in how thread(s) are interacting to guess the source of the problem.

Just adding the logging can in itself solve the problem because it alters the timing of code.  Sucks when that happens.

Comment: Yeah I know, if I add a Thread.Sleep everything works. Well I'll keep looking :-)

Answer (score 1):

I assume OnRead is firing an event dispatched on a thread pool thread. If any registered event handler is writing to `amessage`, its value could change any time you're in the reading loop.

Still not very clear where you are gettingthe value assigned to `amessage` in the loop. Should `cleanmessage` read `content`?

Comment: This is probably a stupid question but I though a string is a value type and doesn't reference the address like a reference type. 

EDIT: Sorry it is a reference type but immutable so I don't understand how it could change in the OnRead event

Comment: Quite right... I didn't mean to imply that writing to the copy in the CommandEventArgs object would change amessage, just that if there was any other code in the type which writes to amessage, triggered by the event firing, that might explain it.